# Nested ListView scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows

I am having some issues in my Windows 8.1 app regarding getting a nested `ListView`  to scroll properly. Basically I have the following scenario:

I have a page that needs to display a list of 'packages' in a vertical `ListView`. Each of those packages then has 1-15 images inside of it that I would then like to display in a horizontal `ListView`. Basically this means I have a list of lists that I would like to display (display the main list vertically, and for each list in the vertical list, list the images horizontally).

I have this almost working, but when it comes to trying to scroll through the nested `ListView` of images, it is very difficult because the scroll bar/area is right below the images and most of the time you end up touching the image and "selecting" it instead. I'd like to be able to swipe to scroll but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Is there a better way to approach getting a nested horizontal listview to scroll properly? I think one of the issue may be that my touch events aren't being routed the way I want them to be.

At this point my `XAML` for this looks like the following:

```
   <ScrollViewer x:Name="OuterScrollView">
        <ListView x:Name="ImageRoot" Height="851" Width="656" DataContext="{StaticResource GlobalDataContext}" ItemsSource="{Binding MainImageInfo.ImagePackages}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding PackageName}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <ListView>
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageBitmap}" Height="200" Width="200"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the selection behaviour? That is, are you intending to do something when an item is selected, or is that just an unwanted side-effect of what you are trying to achieve visually?